# Dynamic partition on multiple columns hive

Tags: mysql, hadoop, hive

I have a file with multiple columns ,two among those columns are year and month. 
I am trying to do a dynamic partition on the table based on these 2 columns year and month.

I tried the below command:

`load data inpath '/com/data/abc.txt' into table ABC_TABLE partition (year,month);`

Below exception is what I get:

`FAILED: SemanticException org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: MetaException(message:Invalid partition key & values; keys [year_cd, quarter_num, ], values [])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are loading data, you need to mention the details of the partition, based on the column value. See below syntax, provided by clouder.

```
LOAD DATA INPATH 'hdfs_file_or_directory_path' [OVERWRITE] INTO TABLE tablename [PARTITION (partcol1=val1, partcol2=val2 ...)]
```

This is a static approach. if you need dynamic, look into [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/DynamicPartitions) and practical example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26708316/how-to-dynamically-partition-the-table-based-on-week-by-using-date-in-hive)